# how to make use of a class which implements IExtenderProvider?

Tags: c#, .net

I have written an extender provider. I have that class in a file in solution explorer (marked with component icon).

Now, how can i "install", "placed" it on the form ...so that all components on the form which can extend their properties from my class could retrieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop it from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

If you don't see it then you might have a setting wrong.  Tools + Options, Windows Forms Designer, General.  Ensure that the AutoToolboxPopulate property is at its default value, True.

Comment: Thank you. I have had it set to false.